# Mongoose - What is the third argument passed to the `model.save` callback?

Tags: save, arguments, mongoose

```
var product = new ProductSchema();
model.save(function(err, product, number) {
});
```

What is the `number` argument stands for?

Answer (score 4):

It is the number of documents that were affected:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save